# Cant load modules/mod_wsgi.so into server; technologies=Django1.8 + Apache + mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

On kubuntu 14.04 am configuring django project(virtual env) to run in xampp using mod_wsgi in python3.4

so for that i installed mod_wsgi for python3 by command

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

after that enabled it using command

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi
```

in httpd.conf things i have added as follows

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/lampp/htdocs/parth/virtualenvironments/python3.4.3/django_1.8.1_Projects/trial/trial/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /opt/lampp/htdocs/parth/virtualenvironments:/opt/lampp/htdocs/parth/virtualenvironments/python3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages
<Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/parth/virtualenvironments/python3.4.3/django_1.8.1_Projects/trial/trial>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

as per some solution i have commented following code

```
#<Directory />
 #AllowOverride none
#Require all denied
#</Directory>
```

The exact error am getting is

> httpd: Syntax error on line 158 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf: Cannot
>   load modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: /opt/lampp/modules/mod_wsgi.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Now As per loadmodule says that module should be under **modules/mod_wsgi.so**
but i cant find **mod_wsgi.so** in my modules folder under path **/opt/lampp/modules/**

when i type `locate mod_wsgi.so`
 it gives output

```
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so-2.7
```

and when i add `LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so`
 to file then it gives error like

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 158 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt
```

So, what's the problem.
Thanks